# Adding a column with files name where data comes from

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list of files within a folder that I access via glob:

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('my_path/*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv("my_path", index=False)
```

I would like to add a new column before saving the file which include the file name where data comes from.
For example: if I've in a folder 7 files ['file1.csv', 'another_one.csv', ...], all of them having the same columns' names (e.g., 'Name', 'Surname', 'Country'), how can I include another column 'File' where I have for all data that comes from file1

```
'Name' 'Surname' 'Country' 'File'
...     ...       ...      file1.csv
... 
...                        file1.csv
___     ___       ___      another_one.csv
```

and so on?

Comment: `combined_csv['File'] = all_filenames`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, I have tried it, but it returns ValueError: Length of values (102) does not match length of index (25000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('my_path/*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(File=lambda x: f.split('/')[-1]) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv("my_path", index=False)
```

Comment: I modify my code, re-try it : i id `f.split('/')[-1]`